# Firebase ChildAdded doesn't populate tableView if no new items exist

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the code below, I query for all new posts using the posted date and childAdded, but it seems that when there isn't a new item, the table view doesn't show any items but the firebase block still runs? Please help. I did add number of rows in section. I don't know why stack overflow won't show.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "postedDate").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

        if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
          print("Has children")

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {



                let imageCount = dictionary["Images"]?.count

                // Post not saved
                if (imageCount == nil) {
                    print("image count is nil")
                }

                    // better catch
                else if (imageCount! < 3) {
                    print("not all 3 were posted")

                }

                    // Saved post
                else {

                    // Adding to details array
                    self.keyArray.append(snapshot.key)

                    // Inside a for loop to get every Image
                    for index in 1 ..< dictionary["Images"]!.count + 1 {

                        // Check = image1, image2 ...
                        let check = "image" + String(index)


                        // Put into the imageArray dictionary
                        self.imageArray[check] = dictionary["Images"]?[check] as! String?

                    }


                    // Handles adding the key and appending the image
                    self.imageArray2[snapshot.key] = self.imageArray
                    self.imageArray3.append(self.imageArray2)



                    // No images but actual values

                    // Creating makeEasy variables
                    var valuesArray = [String: String]()



                    // Adding values to specific array
                    let name = dictionary["Itemname"] as? String?



                    // I have all items
                    if (name != nil) {

                        // Add values to valueArray
                        valuesArray["name"] = name!


                        // Add the Key: UUID
                        self.details[snapshot.key] = valuesArray

                        // Then put in the actual array
                        self.detailsArr.append(self.details)

                    }

                        // I DONT have all items
                    else {

                        print("Not present!!")

                    }


                    // Removing
                    self.imageArray.removeAll()
                    self.imageArray2.removeAll()
                    valuesArray.removeAll()
                    self.details.removeAll()

                }

            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        else {
            print("Has NO children")
        }
    })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.imageArray3.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "viewTableCell", for: indexPath) as! viewTableViewCell


    // get the key first and CHECK IF IT EXISTS ******
    let key = keyArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.name.text = self.detailsArr[indexPath.row][key]!["name"]

    // cache the pic
    if let pic = self.imageArray3[indexPath.row][key]?["image1"] {
        cell.itemImage.load(pic)

    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Set the key and the index
    self.tappedIndex = indexPath.row
    self.currentKey  = keyArray[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mystify", sender: self)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 400
}
```

Comment: `childAdded` will only fire when a child exists. If you want an event that also fires when no children exist, use `value`.

Comment: Thanks for the respond mate!! but with .value it won't let me query the children with the most recent one being first using the FIRserver timestamp? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The query capabilities are exactly the same between `.value` and `.child*`. The difference is that you will need to loop over the children of the snapshot when you use a `.value` event.

Comment: thank you so much, if you could comment, ill like ur answer :) Also any idea on how you could get the firebase query of the newest post first when using .value and FIRServer timestamp? I tried the code underneath and still got random values...........FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "postedDate").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

Comment: Mr. Frank??????

Comment: WHOOP after two days I figured it out!! preciate it Frank

Comment: To anyone stuck, this link explains it better than I could:  http://techqa.info/programming/question/39421105/swift-firebase-sort-by-last-10-and-then-show-10-new-values

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: "last timestamp in tableview", childKey: "timestamp").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

Comment: Original for that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421105/swift-firebase-sort-by-last-10-and-then-show-10-new-values (which loads a lot faster for me)

Comment: awesome man!!!!